# simulink - GetSet Custom Storage Class

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am having a model which takes two input & multiplies them & give the output.
output_1 = input_1 * input_2

I have declared my simulink signals as CustomStorageClass= GetSet

```
   input_1 = Simulink.Signal;
   input_1.CoderInfo.StorageClass = 'Custom';
   input_1.CoderInfo.CustomStorageClass = 'GetSet';
   input_1.CoderInfo.CustomAttributes.GetFunction = 'Get_input_1';
   input_1.CoderInfo.CustomAttributes.SetFunction = 'Set_input_1';
   input_1.CoderInfo.CustomAttributes.HeaderFile = 'signals.h';


   input_2 = Simulink.Signal;
   input_2.CoderInfo.StorageClass = 'Custom';
   input_2.CoderInfo.CustomStorageClass = 'GetSet';
   input_2.CoderInfo.CustomAttributes.GetFunction = 'Get_input_2';
   input_2.CoderInfo.CustomAttributes.SetFunction = 'Set_input_2';
   input_2.CoderInfo.CustomAttributes.HeaderFile = 'signals.h';



   output_1 = Simulink.Signal;
   output_1.CoderInfo.StorageClass = 'Custom';
   output_1.CoderInfo.CustomStorageClass = 'GetSet';
   output_1.CoderInfo.CustomAttributes.GetFunction = 'Get_output_1';
   output_1.CoderInfo.CustomAttributes.SetFunction = 'Set_output_1';
   output_1.CoderInfo.CustomAttributes.HeaderFile = 'signals.h';
```

Now I am trying to convert my model to code using simulink coder.
In code generation setting of the model i have selected `ert.tlc` file in the system target file settings.

But the generated code does not have a Get_input_1() or  Get_input_2() call like shown in this link.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/ecoder/ug/getset-custom-storage-classes.html

What i have missed in the setting. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I know you probably already solved this issue, but I have also seen this behavior before.

Sometimes MATLAB does not update the header files correctly. If you had set a different configuration for your variable and then made a change involving the header files, I would recommend erasing the *_ert_rtw and slprj folders (they will appear again). It is similar to doing a "Make clean" operation, to ensure that everything is brand new.